# How to keep from having repeated items on a tableView due to a function triggered several times?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, duplicates

My issue is that I am querying elements in viewDidLoad and adding to the tableView. On another view, the user can add elements to Parse, that I am querying again on viewDidAppear to display only the newly added elements without requiring the view to re-load.
These elements are class of user with name, age etc...

On the viewDidAppear, I am querying the elements from Parse, going through a messy filtering to find out the ones that are not already displayed on the tableView, and then I trigger my function to add it.

It appears that even though I have removed duplicate items from my array, the function to set up my user (adding his name etc) gets called several times and consequently I still end up with duplicated items on my tableView.

The corresponding codes as below:

```
      override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {


    var query = PFUser.query()

    query!.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)


    query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, NSError) -> Void in



        if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

            for member in objects {

                if member["Network"] != nil {

                    var acceptedMembers: [String] = member["Network"] as! [String]

                    self.usernames = acceptedMembers

                    ////

                    var query2 = PFUser.query()

                    query2?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects2, error2) -> Void in

                        if let objects2 = objects2 as? [PFUser] {

                            for otherUser in objects2 {

                                if contains(self.usernames, otherUser.username!) {


                                   var arrayName1 = [String]()

                                    arrayName1.append(otherUser.username!)

                                    var arrayName2 = [String]()

                                    for n in self.arrayMem {

                                     arrayName2.append(n.name)

                                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                                        for extra in arrayName1 {

                                            if contains(arrayName2, extra) {

                                            } else {

                                                var arrayName3 = [String]()

                                                arrayName3.append(extra)


                                               let unique3 = NSSet(array: arrayName3).allObjects

                                               self.plusOne = unique3.first as! String

                                                self.nameMember = self.plusOne as String

                                                self.setName()

                                                 self.tableView.reloadData()

                                             }
                                            }
                                          })
                                        }

                                   }}}})    }}}}
                               }
```

PS: I have tried cleaner solution to remove duplicate, converting my class to Hashable, then Equatable and using a simple function, however it turns up that this solution, messier as it is works more efficiently. 
Anyway, the question here touches the function "self.setName()" that gets called repeatedly.

Do you have any idea how could this be fixed ?
Thank you infinitely,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different approach would be to add a new object to your array after it's added in the other view controller and then add a new row for it into your table view. I would suggest communicating the newly formed object via an NSNotification.

**View Controller with Table**

Fetch your objects from Parse here, do it once in viewDidLoad

```
func fetchParseObjects () {}
```

Add an observer for this class to the NSNotificationCenter, also in viewDidLoad

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "objectUpdated:", name: "objectUpdated", object: nil)
```

Remove the observer in a deinit method

```
deinit {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "objectUpdated", object: nil)
}

func objectUpdated(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let yourKindOfObject = notification.object as? YOUR_TYPE_HERE {

        // Add, update or remove an item from the array that holds the original fetched data here based on the object
        // Update your tableView accordingly (add, remove or update)
    }
```

Where I have done something similarly I have created a custom object to hold some properties of what object needs to be updated and how it should be updated.

**View Controller that Updates**

Do what you normally do, but send a notification with a descriptive object to use to update your original data accordingly

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("objectUpdated", object: YOUR_OBJECT_WITH_UPDATE_DATA)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried adding the object from the other view controller through a segue, but I still ended up with duplicates. As when I check "if contains(array, element) { } else { " to add the object when the array does not contain the element, for every non-similar element, the action will be performed and I will end up with: 2 duplicates if the array contains two other (different) elements, 3 if it contains 3 etc...

Comment: My answer would be on the premise that you no longer refresh your data source when the view re-appears, only once when it's loaded and then the logic would manage it after that

Comment: Can you expand a little on your hypothesis please ? I dont quite follow.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ll give it a shot right now and update you right away.

Comment: You rock !    Thanks a lot, works perfectly. Just learned a great new stuff.  Thanks again.